# hide heading if no div below

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide

I have some layers like so

```
<div class="evenprop">some prop</div>
<div class="evenprop">some prop2</div>
<div class="evenprop">some prop3</div>

<h3 class="otherprop">Other Props</h3>

<div class="evenprop">some prop4</div>
<div class="evenprop">some prop5</div>
```

This is fine but I need to hide the "otherprop" class if the data looks like this

```
<div class="evenprop">some prop</div>
<div class="evenprop">some prop2</div>
<div class="evenprop">some prop3</div>
<div class="evenprop">some prop4</div>
<div class="evenprop">some prop5</div>

<h3 class="otherprop">Other Props</h3>
```

The layers are dynamically put in so not sure how to do this I somehow need to say if there is no data below the class"otherprop" then hide "otherprop" if that makes sense

The desired result if no data below is

```
<div class="evenprop">some prop</div>
<div class="evenprop">some prop2</div>
<div class="evenprop">some prop3</div>
<div class="evenprop">some prop4</div>
<div class="evenprop">some prop5</div>
```

but if there is data below

```
<div class="evenprop">some prop</div>
<div class="evenprop">some prop2</div>
<div class="evenprop">some prop4</div>
<div class="evenprop">some prop5</div>

<h3 class="otherprop">Other Props</h3>

<div class="evenprop">some prop3</div>
```

Many thanks

Jamie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers but this is how I got my desired result in the end

```
if ($('.property > .evenprop').is(':visible')){
            $('.otherprop').show();
        } else {
            $('.otherprop').hide();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
var nxtSib = document.getElementsByClassName('otherprop')[0].NextSibling;
if(nxtSib != 'evenprop')
    nxtSib.style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your CSS:

```
.otherprop:last-child {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you dynamically change the data there, you could check if any such things are there, like so...

```
var op = $('.otherprop');
if(op.nextAll('div').length) {
    op.show();
else {
    op.hide();
}
```

Instead of using `op.show()` and `op.hide()`, I'd also recommend using `op.addClass('available')` and `op.removeClass('available')` with the following accompanying css

```
.otherprop {
    display: none;
}
.otherprop.available {
    display: block;
}
```

Untested, but should work.